# How to vertically center the text in a paragraph block?

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I get from that :

[image: from that]

to that :

[image: to that]

?

Is there a css property to get this result ? I'm aware of vertical-align But that is only for inline elements when they are altogether with more height-wide element ones.
Any idea ?

Comment: If it is just one line of text you can use `padding` or `line-height`.

Comment: for some reason ppl hated my "try vertical-align:middle" answer, what's so bad about it?

Comment: @heytools Does it work? Show a sample!

Comment: @heytools Did you read my post ? I down-voted your answer because first you just answer what I already know and second that can't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin / padding / line height`

```
p #copyright {margin-top: 10px;}
```

or

```
p #copyright {padding-top: 10px;}
```

or

```
p #copyright {line-height: 25px;}
```

Here is an article that can help you understand it better:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Comment: Only if the content is not dynamic, you have to fudge the numbers for the content

Answer (score 1):

If the content is fixed (The actual words that make up "Copyright" will never change), then you should go with Nave Tseva's solution.

For vertically aligning dynamic content though, you can use `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` to accomplish the vertical centering. Although, a more cross-browser compatible solution is to actually wrap that content in a single table cell, and set `valign="middle"`.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle">
      <p>Copyright</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I know most people would frown on using a table for non-delinated single entry content like this as that's not actually a situation where tables are the appropriate element... but then again, in a perfect world we wouldn't be taking IE shittiness into consideration either.

Comment: +1 This is the old school solution if you need it to work for older browsers, for a table-less solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flex box layout, that is, you don't need support for older browsers, you can use something like the following. The CSS is kind of jacked to support different browsers, but they are converging...

```
#content {
   display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
   display: -moz-box;      /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */ 
   display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21+ */
   display: flex;          /* NEW: Opera 12.1, Firefox 22+ */

   -webkit-box-align: center; -moz-box-align: center; /* OLD… */
   -ms-flex-align: center; /* You know the drill now… */
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;

   -webkit-box-pack: center; -moz-box-pack: center; 
   -ms-flex-pack: center; 
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;

   margin: 0;
   height: 500px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

#content p{
    border: 1px blue solid;
    box-flex:1
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Here's everything that I can think of to put into one line. Have to add more fillter to make sure it works for multiple lines too, yay-ah</p>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/C4WTE/ and the [flexbox playground](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/)

If you really need this to work in older browsers, I'd just give up and use tables like [relic180 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17473861/227299) http://ajaxian.com/wp-content/images/giveupandusetables.png